# ReportViewer web control without authentication

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, reportviewer

I use ReportViewer web server control on a web page. The goal is to have a page that will allow anonymous access. I'm creating a dummy FormsAuthentication cookie that expires in 5 seconds and try to call the report. I also derive from IReportServerCredential and pass in Domain administrator's credentials to the report server. Weird thing is that this approach works fine if i run the web site on VS 2008 and access it from Firefox or IE. I get reports to display. I am also able to host the web site on my Dev box in IIS and view the report in both FF and IE. But as soon as i deploy the web site to production box, I can no longer view reports on IE, but still can on FF. Reports are shown both in IE and FF if a user logs in and opens the page afterward. Web Server and Report Server are two different machines on the same network, same domain. IIS on the production box has impersonation enablet to impersonate domain admin. IIS on both, Dev and Prod boxes has correct http handler mapped for report cpontrol .axd
Any thoughts and suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closely examining the request in Fiddler it appeared that Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd was treated as a separate physical file by IE and it couldn't access it due to permissions. After adding

```
<location path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

to web config, it worked